# How can I get my information to pass from my VB application to my Access Database table?

Tags: vb.net

So this is the code that I am using:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim dtmSystemDate As Date
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim Student As Double = Nothing

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBeginWorkout.Click

        Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim Start As String = "Start"

        ' Set date/time to today's date/time.
        dtmSystemDate = Now()


        ' Convert txtIDNumber to a Double.
        Try
            Student = CDbl(txtIDNumber.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        ' Determine if input is a valid ID number.
        If Student >= 10000 And Student <= 99999 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Your start time is " & dtmSystemDate.ToString("F"), "Welcome, Student # " & Student.ToString())
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid College ID number", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation
                            )
        End If

        cnn.ConnectionString = "provider = microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source = C:\users\econnelly\My Documents\Access Databases\Fit Track.mdb"
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Fit Track (Student_ID,Start/Stop,Date/Time) values ('" & Student & "','" & Start & "', '" & dtmSystemDate & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnn.Close()
```

I am attempting to pass these defined variables to an Access Database and so far have been unsuccessful.

Whenever I try to run my program, I get the following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

This error is triggering from the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() function though I am not sure why.

As of yet, I have been unable to get the information to populate into the database at all. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to address this issue?

Comment: a) start with a valid connection string b) never concat bits of string to make SQL use SQL parameters  c) connections and command need to be Disposed when you are done with them to prevent leaks d) use sensible column name - somethign which does not need to be escaped e) dont use empty Try/Catch blocks

Comment: It looks like `Fit Track` is the name of your database, is it also the name of the table you want to insert into?  Also, you will need to enclose your table and column names in brackets like `[Start/Stop]` for them to be recognized as names.

Comment: @Plutonix - this is my first attempt at connecting to an access database. What is the problem with my connection string?

Comment: www.connectionstrings.com  BTW you can make the connstr form level so you only have to create it once

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with the table name "Fit Track" that has a space in it.

You could use square brackets like [Fit Track]
or you could use single quotes like 'Fit Track'

Comment: I agree, They should remember how to create the not required but the most used format in creating tables and fields. I think he just need to avoid the `[space]` and use `[underscore]` and it will be perfect

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but I've ran into trouble when using spaces or special characters, like slashes, in database Table or Column names. Also, I think your connection string is incorrect. You might also want to read a little bit about SQL injection, it can be dangerous.

EDIT: You might also need to import System.Data.Oledb